# Using case expression in DATEADD interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dateadd

Is possible to use case expression inside of DATEADD interval parameter?

```
select DATEADD(case c1 when 1 then HOUR when 2 then DAY end, c2, date) from T
```

**Update1**: Sorry, I want to use it in where clause

```
select * from T where DATEADD(case c1 when 1 then HOUR when 2 then DAY end, c2, date) < GETDATE()
```

Maybe there is another alternative.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try this - `select case c1 when 1 then DATEADD(HOUR, c2, date) when 2 then DATEADD(DAY, c2, date) end from T`

Comment: I'd guess NO. But why not try?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana It think it should work, but It want to use DATEADD in where clause. I´m updating the example

Comment: @fravelgue I have posted an answer.. you can give that a try..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below..

```
select * from T 
where case c1 when 1 then DATEADD(HOUR, c2, date) 
when 2 then DATEADD(DAY, c2, date) 
end < Getdate()
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot parameterize the `datepart` parameter of [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

> The following table lists all valid *datepart* arguments. User-defined variable equivalents are not valid.

You'll have to use two different `DATEADD` expressions, or change your logic:

```
select DATEADD(hour, c2 * case c1 when 1 then 1 when 2 then 24 end, date) from T
```

Comment: Thanks Damien, I have updated with new example. I read MSDN, and I´m searching an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

you can make query without `CASE`

```
select * from T 
where c1=1 AND DATEADD(hour, c2, date) < getdate()
or c1=2 AND DATEADD(day, c2, date) < getdate()
```

Comment: Case can be used in Where clause.. Read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddf06f4b-53b6-4c44-80aa-a94b7ce10884/tsql-using-case-statement-in-where-clause-multiple-conditions?forum=transactsql) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) .. I'm voting it down for incorrect information...

Comment: Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/220a5/1) for your information. And you can see my answer too on this question...